# In what scenario would Classpath of a java project will be different from its Buildpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, buildpath

Was just looking at `Buildpath` and `Classpath` for my `Java` project in `Eclipse`. I noticed all jars included in my project's buildpath are automatically included its classpath.

It makes sense why Eclipse does that. I mean , If I need to instantiate an external class in my code then I need those classes in by buildpath for the code to compile. And at runtime i need those very same classes loaded into the jvm too.

It then looks like all classes included in the buildpath are needed in classpath. Although I cannot think of a case where a project's classpath will be different from its buildpath .

**Is the above understanding accurate ? Could you give me a scenario where classpath will have additional classes than those in the buildpath ?**

Comment: Let's say you depend on library A for your project, and A internally uses library B, which internally uses library C. Do you need B and C to build the app? No. Do you need them to run it? Yes, since A needs B and B needs C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many situations where classes are only needed at runtime, not compile time. One of the most typical is JDBC drivers; code is written/compiled against the JDBC API, but at runtime a driver class must be available on the classpath. There are any number of other examples, especially when you get into various frameworks that have a standard API and differing implementations that can be "injected" at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

A very common example is classes that implement some API, such as the Servlet API. Each container (Tomcat, Jetty, WebSphere) supplies classes that the Web application usually knows nothing about, since it just uses the interfaces.

More broadly, this pattern is used in the Service Provider Interface to enable plugins that implement an interface to be added at runtime.